# Join date and time in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a win form c#  SQL app that stores date in one column and time in the another.

There is only one date time picker on my form and I want to display both date and time values (which are from two separate columns)..

So far this is what I've done

```
Datetime final = datetime. Parse exact (date + " " + time , "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", cultureinfo. Invariant culture);
```

But it throws " string was not recognized as valid datetime" exception on the above line.

Comment: What are the values of `date` and `time` that give that error? Note that a "dd" format requires two digits, use a "d" when there could be one or two (the same goes for the other specifiers).

Comment: what is the value of `date` and `time`

Comment: What type are the date and time variables? If they are DateTime, you are forcing a DateTime to string conversion using the local culture, before you try to parse back to DateTime using the Invariant culture

Comment: you could even use class as a variable name provided you use DateTime @class :)  Hidden jams of C#

Comment: @AmitJoki you're right, it's [`finally` in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx) of the try-catch block, but still I would use a better name for the variable

Comment: Posted via andriod app... All syntax is correct on visual studio.. All variable names are also within naming rules

Comment: @REZR.AMX Are the variables strings or DateTime ?

Comment: @Panagiotis all variables are date time

Comment: @REZR.AMX then why are you parsing them?

Comment: Then why aren't you simply adding the date element of the first with the time element of the second?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 string d = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
 string t = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm"); 
 var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(t, @"h\:mm",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)+ts;
```

Hope this helps,
Thanks.

Comment: There's no reason either to convert or parse strings when working with dates and timespans. That's what caused the problem in the first place. BTW this code *will* fail if run in locales that have '-' as a date separator (eg German), as it mixes different cultures in the conversion and parsing

Comment: Dear panagiotis Kanavos, parsing is needed here to serve the purpose. Won't this work if i provide the format with the specific seperator? however, downvote was not necessary in that case.

Answer (score 2):

If `date` and `time` are `DateTime` variables, you can combine them with date arithmetic:

```
DateTime date=...;
DateTime time = ...;

DateTime finalDate = date.Date + time.TimeOfDay;
```

If they are strings, you can parse them to DateTime and TimeSpan variables:

```
DateTime date=DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,dateFormat,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.ParseExact(timeString,timeFormat,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime finalDate = date.Date + time;
```

This is possible because you can add a DateTime and a TimeSpan value to get a new DateTime value

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Got valuable inputs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TimeSpan.Parse` to parse

```
DateTime newDateTime = date.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(time));
```

Comment: This will probably fail as well because it assumes a specific format for the time string

Comment: Still the same string is not valid date time exception